# Strange Monte Carlo Sampling Phenomena

Tags: finance

I am running a Monte Carlo simulation to price call and put options, and observe a strange correlation between the number of sampling points and the standard deviation. It makes sense that as the number of sampling points approaches infinity that the standard deviation  would decrease; however, my results do not show this.

I am observing the following trend during testing and cannot make sense of it:

For a call option, the error increases as the number of sampling points increases. For a put option, the error decreases as the number of sampling points increases.

Is it possible for the aforementioned correlation to exist in a Monte Carlo simulation for option pricing formula?

Comment: Does parity hold in your simulation?  If not, then you have a bias somewhere.

Comment: It holds tautologically or it holds numerically?

Comment: @lulu The call-put parity holds numerically

Comment: @lulu - is there any logic to my observation?

Comment: But then I don't understand.  I thought you said that the error in the Call price goes up, and the error in the Put goes down...so surely the error in the difference can't be 0.

Comment: @lulu Thanks anyway

Comment: How are you calculating the standard deviation? Also, how fast does it increase or decrease?